# Meaning of OverflowError message

Tags: python-3.x

In python, an `OverflowError` is raised when the number we are trying to compute is so large that it cannot be represented in a built-in `float` object, which I think is limited to 32 bits. I would like to understand the full meaning of the message printed by `OverflowError` in the following example:

```
>>> 10.1 ** 400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

What does `34` stand for in this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the built-in error code. Each error type is assigned a different error code. For instance for OSerror, expect to see 25 as the error code. You can see other built-in error types here: https://pymotw.com/2/exceptions/